# Is the create disk image in the disks utility like clonezilla?

Tags: 13.04, clonezilla, disk-image

In Ubuntu 13.04, the GUI disks utility has the "create  disk image" feature. Is it like a disk image that Clonezilla can produce ?

If yes, let say I save an image of my HDD which contains my OS to another HDD.

After some time, if I'm not happy with the state of my OS, can I go back to the saved state using the restore disk image feature of the disks utility ?

Comment: I would recommend **fsarchiver** which saves only used data from partition(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Disk Image feature is not yet completely as smart as things like GNU ddrescue, but saving an image using disks is like making an ISO file from a CD. Its great if you want to save them for long term archival, but it's not a disk-duplicator.

My personal opinion, from dealing with data recovey for quite some time, use something like [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) or [dd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd).

I hope that this help.

Comment: I'll take a closer look at dd then. Thanks Mitch.

Comment: Glad to help.  Good luck :)

Comment: Hi @Mitch what exactly is the "not yet completely as smart ... it is great if save them for long term archival, but it is not a disk-duplicator" part mean? Did you hint that the image created by the Ubuntu built-in GUI disk utility can only be restored to the SAME disk? Thanks in advance for your insight.

Comment: @RayLuo Take a look [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/568807/disk-image-feature-in-disks-utility-has-anyone-used-it/568837#568837).